# Matching an array field which contains any combination of the provided array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to query with a specified list of array elements such that documents returned can only contain the elements I pass, but need not contain all of them.

Given documents like:

```
{
  name: "Article 1",
  tags: ["Funny", "Rad"]
}

{
  name: "Article 2",
  tags: ["Cool", "Rad"]
}

{
  name: "Article 3",
  tags: ["Rad"]
}
```

Here are some example arrays and their respective results.

- `["Rad"]` should return Article 3
- `["Rad", "Cool"]` should return Article 2 and Article 3
- `["Funny", "Cool"]` should return nothing, since there are no articles with only one of those tags or both

I'm sure I can pull this off with `$where` but I'd like to avoid that for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by combining multiple operators:

```javascript
db.test.find({tags: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: ['Rad', 'Cool']}}}})
```

The `$elemMatch` with the `$nin` is finding the docs where a single `tags` element is neither 'Rad' nor 'Cool', and then the parent `$not` inverts the match to return all the docs where that didn't match any elements.

However, this will also return docs where `tags` is either missing or has no elements.  To exclude those you need to add a qualifier that ensures `tags` has at least one element:

```javascript
db.test.find({
    tags: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: ['Rad', 'Cool']}}},
    'tags.0': {$exists: true}
})
```

Comment: Wanted to follow up on this and mention that a few months later this no longer works for us due to the increased size of our collection. Because this query uses `$nin` and `$not` Mongo must do a full collection scan in order to perform the query.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works, but isn't optimised. Since this is the top result on Google, here's a better solution.

I went all the way back to version 2.2 in the docs, which is the oldest version available, and all of them state:

> If the `field` holds an array, then the [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array (e.g. `<value1>`, `<value2>`, etc.)

[Source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

So you can just do

```
db.test.find({tags: {$in: ['Rad', 'Cool']}})
```

which will return any entries where the tags contain either 'Rad', 'Cool', or both *and* use an index if available.