# Exact Match Array in Mongo Query

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

Using Linq syntax, how would you exact match an array inside of a document?

This query works great except that it matches documents who have other Children with ages not 3 or 4.

```
    var query = collection.AsQueryable<Parent>().Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Age == 3) && p.Children.Any(c => c.Age == 4));
```

For example, it should NOT return this document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5514c620923a9b55e22f0adf"),
    "Name" : "Bob",
    "Children" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid1",
            "Age" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid2",
            "Age" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid3",
            "Age" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

And should match this document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5514c620923a9b55e22f0adf"),
    "Name" : "Bob",
    "Children" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid2",
            "Age" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Kid3",
            "Age" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

This is basically a duplicate of this question, but using linq c# syntax.

> [Matching an array field which contains any combination of the provided array in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318050/matching-an-array-field-which-contains-any-combination-of-the-provided-array-in)

Bonus points if you can also show it using c# QueryBuilder instead of linq.

Comment: How about : `collection.AsQueryable<Parent>().Where(p => p.Children.All(c => new[]{3,4}.Contains(c.Age));` ?

Comment: `$all: [3,4]` will also match if the document contains `[3,4,5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another array, which includes a distinct list of the ages. I.e.:

```
{
  ages: [3,4],
  children: [
    { name: "A", age: 3 },
    { name: "A", age: 4 },
    { name: "A", age: 3 }
  ]
}
```

Now you can use the `$all` query: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Combined with the `$size` query: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/

```
{ ages: { $all: [3,4], $size: 2 } }
```

Comment: I think this is close, how do you do $size in Linq and QueryBuilder in c#?