# MongoDB Aggregate - Exclude if match, with a twist

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My goal is to find songs that match user's choices. User has the opportunity to exclude genres he doesn't like.

[This is basically a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318050/matching-an-array-field-which-contains-any-combination-of-the-provided-array-in), except that I'd like to be able to do this in an `Aggregate` operation instead of a `Find`, as I need to add other stages.

Right now, I am trying in an aggregation to exclude songs that belong to genres user doesn't like.

My song json is as such (keep in mind this is dummy data - but this song is really good though):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5890aa3b0a9f110011698fac"
    },
    "artist": "Beach House", 
    "songName": "Master Of None",
    "genres": [
        {
            "$oid": "58624b4298fba881a46663a01"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "58624b9d98fba772a46663a05"
        }
    ]
}
```

A song can have multiple genres, stored in an array of objects as references to Genre documents in a different collection.

Basically, user's disliked genres are in an array of genre `$oid`. 
Say

```
dislikedGenres = [ "786761gg1G176ga1", "78676187g1G176hsj3", "78676187g1G1761sj4" ]
```

What I'm trying to do is say "if you find a song with any of these genres, exclude it".

Any idea how to achieve this? I feel like I'm missing something dramatically obvious here...

Thanks in advance for the help! Much appreciated.
Please leave a comment if you need extra info.

Comment: just put the content of the `find()` query in a **`$match`** stage

Comment: Will try that now. Didn't even know that was possible... Will update! Thanks felix

Comment: Wait, do you mean putting the result of a find() query in the $match stage? That would kinda kill the idea of having just an Aggregation. But maybe I got what you meant wrong.

Comment: sorry my comment wasn't clear enough, I meant the query used in the question you linked. So your **`$match`** stage would look like: `{$match: {genres: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: [ "786761gg1G176ga1", "78676187g1G176hsj3", "78676187g1G1761sj4" ]}}}}}`

Comment: Felix... "My man"! 
https://media.giphy.com/media/qPVzemjFi150Q/giphy.gif
It just works. Thank you so much! Is it allowed to ask you if you have a bitcoin/eth address? :)